# Find the value of

Tags: complex-analysis

$\int_{c}\dfrac {1}{\left( z-\alpha \right) ^{3}}dz$

Where C is some closed anti clockwise contour which does not pass through alpha.

I was thinking to use Cauchys integral formula, but didnt know if it was applicable due to the cubic term on the bottom.

I've got a few questions:

-How would we calculate this 
-What would happen if the contour did go trough alpha ?
-Why does the contour need to be anticlockwise ?

Thanks

Tom

Comment: Orientation of the contour isn't hugely important, that's just a sign difference. There is a singularity at $\alpha$ so the integral blows up if the contour goes through $\alpha$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Cauchy's differentiation formula for a suitable $f$:
$$
f^{(n)}(a) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}\, dz
$$
Or notice that 
$
\dfrac {1}{\left( z-\alpha \right) ^{3}}
$
has a primitive in $\mathbb C \setminus \{\alpha\}$.